# How to convert Gridview data to pdf?

Tags: c#, jquery, pdf

In my gridview I have a checkbox, images and radio button. Now I want to take gridview data as pdf.

My code :

```
    function exporttopdf() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a2');
        pdf.setFontSize(10);
       source = $('#tblgridview')[0]; 
       specialElementHandlers = {
      '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {

                return true
            }
        };
        margins = { top: 30, bottom: 40,  left: 10, width: 1300 };
       pdf.fromHTML(
                source,
                margins.left, 
                margins.top, 
                    'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                },
         function (dispose) {
       pdf.save('sample.pdf');
        }
        , margins);
    }
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnExporttoPDF" ImageUrl="pdf.png" OnClientClick="exporttopdf(); return false;" runat="server" />
```

How to convert Gridview data to pdf?

Comment: Telerik or Devexpress gridviews have features that can easily do this for you.

Comment: @Owuor what if he does not have money?

Comment: @Badiparmagi then it would involve abit of coding on his side, alternatively he can check out this Javascript to pdf converter ( http://www.techumber.com/2015/04/html-to-pdf-conversion-using-javascript.html )